# How to auto start elasticsearch in Centos 6.5?

Tags: linux, centos, elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearh on a server based on Cent OS 6.5. To start it:

```
# cd /usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.5.2]
# ./bin/elasticsearch &
```

But when I close the terminal, the process is killed. How can I set it to automatically start as a service?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it [process] is died by system"? Is there a specific error you are getting?

Comment: You need to start it as a service, not just for evaluation purposes.

See more https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service.html

Comment: Here described only for Ubuntu/Debian

Answer (score 3):

Try using the "nohup" command with elastic search.

```
$ nohup ./bin/elasticsearch
```

Now what the `nohup` does? In the following example, it starts the program abcd in the background in such a way that the subsequent logout does not stop it.

```
$ nohup abcd &
$ exit
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

As @DerStoffel said, you have to start elasticsearch as a service (`sudo service elasticsearch start`). This is highly recommended in production settings. Also add the service to start in case of reboot (`sudo /sbin/chkconfig --add elasticsearch`)

Answer (score 0):

It depends the distribution of linux you use:

Debian/Ubuntu

```
sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10
sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/setup-service.html#_debian_ubuntu

RPM based distributions like Centos

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig --add elasticsearch
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/setup-service.html#_rpm_based_distributions

Answer (score -1):

`sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload`

`sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service`

`sudo /bin/systemctl start elasticsearch.service`